# Verification codes generate endpoint silently fails

Tags: gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to use the generate endpoint to create backup codes for a user. Once every ~200 requests, I receive an empty return, with no notification of failure.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/verificationCodes/generate

Has anyone seen this in the past? is there a workaround here?

Thanks!